# Login password problem

Tags: 12.10, kubuntu, login, login-screen

I am using kubuntu 12.10.

My problem is when my kubuntu starts, in login screen it shows my name & a field for giving password (previously what i have choose for my account). But if at this stage, I hit enter or write anything & hit enter it gets log in!!! So strange! 
( a huge security problem for me!)
But in "sudo" it not working on any password, i have to give my selected password to access sudo!

how can my login problem be solved?!

Comment: I would try to enable autologin and then disable it.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior you describe will occur if the user in question is in the nopasswdlogin group (assuming it's enabled in PAM, which it sounds like it is). You can remove the user from that group with the command `sudo gpasswd -d USERNAME nopasswdlogin`, replacing USERNAME with their actual username.